# Conversion Problem from VS2003 to VS2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to convert a project from vs2003 to vs2005.after conversion completed some include headerfile.h statement missing and generates include "serialize" .how to fix this.even i copy and paste.it prompts for the source would be modified outside the environment msg appears.
what can i do to fix this any idea???

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is it a header file from Visual Studio libraries? Is it your header file? You need to provide more details...

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005 doesn't install all the Platform SDKs Visual Studio 2003 did. You might need to install the platform SDK as well. See my comment to your question.